# What is GKEOP kernel image?

Tags: linux-headers

Just looking through possible linux kernels, I fall on linux-image-gkeop listed using Synaptic Package Manager.. never seen.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/linux-image-gkeop

Answer (score 1):

It's a special kernel for the Google container engine.

Software Description:

- linux: Linux kernel
- linux-aws: Linux kernel for Amazon Web Services (AWS) systems
- linux-azure: Linux kernel for Microsoft Azure Cloud systems
- linux-gcp: Linux kernel for Google Cloud Platform (GCP) systems
- linux-kvm: Linux kernel for cloud environments
- linux-oracle: Linux kernel for Oracle Cloud systems
- linux-raspi: Linux kernel for Raspberry Pi (V8) systems
- linux-gkeop: Linux kernel for Google Container Engine (GKE) systems
- linux-hwe-5.8: Linux hardware enablement (HWE) kernel
- linux-oem-5.10: Linux kernel for OEM systems
- linux-aws-5.4: Linux kernel for Amazon Web Services (AWS) systems
- linux-azure-5.4: Linux kernel for Microsoft Azure cloud systems
- linux-gcp-5.4: Linux kernel for Google Cloud Platform (GCP) systems
- linux-gke-5.3: Linux kernel for Google Container Engine (GKE) systems
- linux-gke-5.4: Linux kernel for Google Container Engine (GKE) systems
- linux-gkeop-5.4: Linux kernel for Google Container Engine (GKE) systems
- linux-hwe: Linux hardware enablement (HWE) kernel
- linux-hwe-5.4: Linux hardware enablement (HWE) kernel
- linux-oracle-5.4: Linux kernel for Oracle Cloud systems
- linux-raspi-5.4: Linux kernel for Raspberry Pi (V8) systems
- linux-raspi2-5.3: Linux kernel for Raspberry Pi (V8) systems

found on:

- https://www.pro-linux.de/sicherheit/2/60448/sicherheit-mehrere-probleme-in-linux.html
- https://ubuntu.com/kernel/variants